# Convert PHP array from mysql to JSON format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to convert the result array from Mysql to JSON format, the format doesn't seems to be correct, a comma is missing between each object. Please advice, thank you.

I'm aware that im using the deprecated version of php here.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patientvaccinedetail")or 
die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {


 $specific = ["message" => $row["message"],
              "mobile" => $row["mobile"]];

             print_r (json_encode($specific)); 
}
```

Current Result:

```
{"message":"hello","mobile":"12345678"}{"message":"hi","mobile":"87878965"}
```

Desired Result:

```
{"message":"hello","mobile":"12345678"}, {"message":"hi","mobile":"87878965"}
```

Comment: Your **Desired Result:**  is not a valid json check [here](https://jsonlint.com/?code=).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use array and at end of loop you have to echo result

```
$specific = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     $specific[] = ["message" => $row["message"],
                  "mobile" => $row["mobile"]];
}
echo json_encode($specific);
```

Comment: And may i ask one more thing, can i remove $specific = array(); , as remove it will get the same result, so i'm just wondering whether it could be removed, thanks

Comment: Yes you can its only for array declaration. But its good practice to initialize array before you concate it.

Comment: sorry , one more Can I still use print_r instead of echo?

Comment: Yes but preferable to use `echo` because the result is string.

Answer (score 0):

Please moved json_encode() to outside of while loop.

```
$specific = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 $specific = ["message" => $row["message"],
              "mobile" => $row["mobile"]];          
}
print_r(json_encode($specific));
```